# Android Dropbox upload temporary file

Tags: android, inputstream, dropbox-api

Im trying to send a temporary file to dropbox.
Images on /sdcard/ are working, but with this code I get a DropboxIOException.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

File outputDir = getCacheDir();
File outputFile = File.createTempFile("tmp", ".tmp", outputDir);
OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));

//Do something with the Image
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);

FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(outputFile);

//Upload to Dropbox with: "outputFile.getName()", "in" and "outputFile.length()"
```

data comes from an intent and is a content URI.
Stacktrace:

```
com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxIOException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.execute(RESTUtility.java:424)
at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI$BasicUploadRequest.upload(DropboxAPI.java:1280)
at test.SendAsync.doInBackground(SendAsync.java:32)
at test.SendAsync.doInBackground(SendAsync.java:17)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:557)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.execute(RESTUtility.java:387)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException: Cannot retry request with a non-repeatable request entity
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:420)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
... 12 more
```

SendAsync (works with static images on external storage)

```
    DropboxAPI.UploadRequest mRequest;

    try {
        mRequest = mDBApi.putFileRequest(outputFile.getName(), in, outputFile.length(), null, null);
        mRequest.upload();
        [...]
```

Comment: None of the code you posted seems to reference Dropbox. Is there more you could add? Also, posting the full stack trace may help.

Comment: Thanks for updating your post. It looks like the underlying cause is `org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException`. Does this happen on multiple devices? Are you able to manually connect to api-content.dropbox.com on the device(s)?

Comment: I just have one device to test, but I can connect to api-content.dropbox.com. When I write the file to be uploaded to external storage everything works fine, just when the file is on internal storage (getCacheDir/getFilesDir) I get this exception. Device is LG G2 with CM12.

Comment: So there seems to be something different about `in`? Can you try reading from it manually in both cases to see if one is somehow broken or behaves differently?

Comment: I don't know what I did, but the EXACT code above works now.